# Fourier transform of a time shifted impulse function

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I am running into a problem with the phase shifted impulse function and its fourier transform:

\begin{array}{l}
X( \omega ) =\int _{-\infty }^{\infty } x( t) e^{-iwt} dt\\
\\
x( t) =\delta ( t-T_{0}) \\
\\
X( \omega ) =\int _{-\infty }^{\infty } \delta ( t-T_{0}) e^{-iwt} dt\\
\end{array}

I then use the sifting property of the impulse function to get:

\begin{array}{l}
X( \omega ) =e^{-iwT_{0}}\\
\end{array}

How do I then interpret this in the frequency domain ? I read this as a cosine over the frequency spectrum. But it should be a impulse in the frequency domain?

Comment: Why are you expecting it to be an impulse in the frequency domain? It sounds like you are expecting it to be sharply localized in both time and frequency and that is asking too much.

Comment: @AHusain How would you visualise this in the frequency domain ?